# Java Generic ? extends String

Tags: java, generics

While I was going through some generics question I came across this example. Will you please explain why `list.add("foo")` and `list = new ArrayList<Object>()` contain compailation issues?

In my understanding List of `? extends String` means "List of Something which extends String", but String is final ? can only be String. In list.add() we are adding "foo" which is a string. Then why this compilation issue?

```
public class Generics {
public static void main(String[] args) {
}

public static void takelist(List<? extends String> list){
    list.add("foo"); //-- > error
    /*
     * The method add(capture#1-of ? extends String) in the 
     * type List<capture#1-of ? extends String> is not applicable 
     * for the arguments (String)
     */

    list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    /*
     * Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<Object> to List<? extends               String>
     */
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Object o = list;
}
```

}

Comment: `Object` does not extend `String`, but it is a `super` type.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, the `java.lang.String` class is *final*, meaning nothing can extend it.  So there is no class which could satisfy the generic requirement `? extends String`.

I believe this problem will cause all of the compiler errors/warnings which you are seeing.

```
list.add("foo");                  // String "foo" does not extend String
list = new ArrayList<Object>();   // list cannot hold Object which does not extend String
```

Comment: It doesn't lead to the second compilation error: you wouldn't be able to make that assignment, even if the parameter were `List<String> list`.

Comment: The OP has already stated that knows String is final.    And the statement List<? extends String> s;   is a perfectly valid declaration.    If I say List<T extends String> that means that T either extends String or it is String itself.

Comment: @Teto If `T extends String` be valid, then why would there be an error when adding `"foo"` to the list?

Comment: @Tim, At compile time, the compiler doesn't know what T is.  If you have a List of T, where T extends String, you can't put a String in that list because at run time T might not be String.  I wasn't suggesting that the user switch from "?" to "T".

Comment: `list = new ArrayList<String>();` is valid, there is no compilation error on that line.

Answer (score 1):

It is true what you say. String is final.  And so you can reason that `List<? extends String>` can only be list of string.

But the compiler isn't going to make that kind of analysis. That is to say, the compiler will not assess the final or non-final nature of String (see comments).  The compiler will only let you put null into your list.

You can pull stuff out though.

```
String s = list.get(0);
```

Comment: To make your answer a bit more explicit, I might add after "that kind of analysis": "the compiler makes no distinction between non-final and final classes with respect to generics".

Comment: I think you should add that no check is being made to see whether or not `String` is a final class at _compile_ time.  So the compiler happily builds your code, but at runtime, since nothing extends `String` (not even `String` itself), you can't add anything to the list.

Comment: @AndyTurner,  Thanks for the help. I made some clarification.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am not sure I understand your remarks.  At run time, the generics become the raw type.  Effectively it is List<Object>.  It will happily let me put whatever I want in there at run time.  It is at compile time that I am prevented from putting anything into "list of something".     If I were allowed to put anything in, even a string, then that would be  a problem at run time if it turned out that "something" was not a string.

Answer (score 1):

While String is final, this information is *not* used.

And in fact, with Java 9, it may no longer be final (rumor has it that Java 9 may finally get different more efficient String types).

Without knowing it is final, `List<? extends String>` could be  e.g. a `List<EmptyString>` of strings that must be empty.

```
void appendTo(List<? extends String> l) {
  l.append("nonempty");
}

appendTo(new ArrayList<EmptyStrings>());
```

would yield a violation of the generic type.

As a rule of thumb always use:

- `? extends Type` for *input* collections (`get` is safe)
- `? super Type` for *output* collections (`put` is safe)
- `Type` (or maybe a `<T>`) for input and output collections (`get` and `put` are safe, but the least permissive).

I.e. this is fine:

```
void appendTo(List<? super String> l) {
  l.append("nonempty");
}

appendTo(new ArrayList<Object>());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already mentioned that `String` is a `final` type and therefore there is no point in repeating this fact. The point that is important to note is that none of the following `List`s allows adding an element:

1. `List<?>` which is a `List` of *anything*.
2. `List<? extends SomeType>` which is a `List` of *anything that extends SomeType*.

Let's understand it with an example.

The `List<? extends Number>` **could be** `List<Number>` or `List<Integer>` or `List<Double>` etc. or even a `List` of some other type that hasn't been defined yet. Since you can not add any type of `Number` to a `List<Integer>` or any type of `Number` to a `List<Double>` etc., Java does not allow it.

Just for the sake of completeness, let's talk about `List<? super Integer>` which is `List` of *anything that is a `super`/parent type of `Integer`*. Will the following compile?

```
Object obj = 10.5;
list.add(obj);
```

As you can guess, of course NOT.

What about the following?

```
Object obj = 10.5;
list.add((Integer) obj);
```

Again, as you can guess, indeed it will compile but it will throw `ClassCastException` at runtime. The question is: why did not Java stop us in the first place by failing the compilation itself? The answer is **Trust**. When you cast something, the compiler trusts that you already understand the cast.

So, the following compiles and runs successfully:

```
Object obj = 10;
list.add((Integer) obj);
list.add(20);
```